# Logical Base Case

Tags: python, recursion

I've got this very simple recursive function:

```
def subL(L):
    x=len(L)
    if x==0:
        return L
    else:
        print(L[:x]) 
        subL(L[:x-1])
```

This is example input I've used:

```
x = [23,2,5,77,8,9]
print(subL(x))
```

This is the output:

```
[23, 2, 5, 77, 8, 9]
[23, 2, 5, 77, 8]
[23, 2, 5, 77]
[23, 2, 5]
[23, 2]
[23]
None
```

How does the base case of this function work `if x==0: return L` ? Is that the reason I am getting `None` in the output? 
Can it be amended to simple produce: the following?

```
[23, 2, 5, 77, 8, 9]
[23, 2, 5, 77, 8]
[23, 2, 5, 77]
[23, 2, 5]
[23, 2]
[23]
```

Comment: the `None` is not printed by the function; it's printed by the interpreter because the function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are not returning the result of the recursive function. Change the recursive line to this

```
return subL(L[:x-1])
```

And if you want to ignore the last `None` alone, invoke the function without `print`, like this

```
subL(x)
```

If you don't explicitly return anything, Python will return `None` by default. That's why you see that `None` being printed.

The entire program can be shortened like this

```
def subL(L):
    if L:
        print(L)
        return subL(L[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little rewrite, it works

```
def subL(L):
    if not L:
        return
    else:
        print L
        subL(L[:-1])
```